# Fade in and afde out on click or hover

Tags: onclick, fadein, fadeout

I have this script:

```
    $('#tooncart').click(function() {
        $('#top-cart').slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });
```

I need a hover on #tooncart, the #top-cart needs to fade-in.
When I move my cursor from the #tooncart the #top-cart needs to stay visible.
When I click on #tooncart again and click on some div with class .closing (which is into #top-cart) it needs to fade out again.

I think it needs to look a little like this:

```
    $('#tooncart').hover(function() {
        $('#top-cart').fadeIn('slow');
          // when click on #tooncard or .closing then fade out! 
          // when directly hover on the #tooncart I think it shouldn't be visible.
    });
```

maybe something like this:

$('.closing').click(function() {
       $(this).parent().fadeOut();

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I have this and it is good:

```
    $('#tooncart').hover(function() {
        $('#top-cart').fadeIn('slow');
        });
        $('.closing').click(function() {
        $('#top-cart').fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

Would be perfect if after click .closing **or** #tooncart then fadeOut!

```
    $('.closing').click(function() // or #tooncart {
    $('#top-cart').fadeOut('slow');
```